# Vertical cell alignment from table generator off

Tags: tables, alignment

I am using a table generator to create several tables as a part of my dissertation. When merging cells, I am having issues with text running out of the bottom of the cell because the vertical alignment seems to default to the top of the bottom-most adjacent cell instead of the top-most adjacent cell. How can I align the text of a merged cell with the top of adjacent cells?

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\textbf{Task} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Associated\\ Strategy\end{tabular}} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Exemplar} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Non-\\ exemplar,\\ other info.\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Topical\\ turn \\ coding\end{tabular}} \\ \hline &  & Explanation & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Definition of term, \\ description of how \\ something works \\ (e.g. treatment), \\ how to complete\\  a task, often related\\  to medical or ED\\  processes\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Interpreter defining \\ colloquial term \\ "mad de orine"\\ which does not have\\ a direct translation\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Falls into updating \\ common ground \\ (not maintaining)\\  when information \\ is known by other \\ communication partners\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Current\\ turn\end{tabular} \\ \cline{3-7} &  &  &  & 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Interpreter arrives, \\ clarifies point in \\ patient's care \\ with registrar\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{5-5} &  & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Bringing \\ up to \\ speed\end{tabular}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Specifically occurs \\ when a new \\ communication \\ partner enters an \\ exchange and are\\  informed about\\  what they have \\ missed in the\\  exchange\end{tabular}} & 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Nurse presenting \\ patient to tele-triage \\ physician\end{tabular} & \multirow{-2}{*}{None} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Current\\ turn\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{3-7}  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}"Let them know you \\ can't swallow pills." - \\ Patient wife to patient\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{5-5} \multirow{-5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Common\\ ground - \\ update\end{tabular}} & \multirow{-5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Describing \\ information \\ known by other \\ communication\\  partners. This\\  may include: \[![enter image description here][1]][1]\ introducing new\\  people to an \\ ongoing joint \\ project or \\ explaining \\ information \\ known by other \\ communication \\ partners.\end{tabular}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Providing/ \\ gaining\\ information\end{tabular}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Catch all for asking\\  for or providing \\ information known\\  by other \\ communication partners \\ (possibly already \\ discussed)\end{tabular}} & 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Patient asking nurse \\ for updates on tests \\ doctor was ordering\end{tabular} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Specific to care of \\ given patient as \\ opposed to explanations\\  of ED or medical \\ processes which would\\ be classified as\\ explanations\end{tabular}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Current\\ turn\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: it would be much easier to answer your question if you completed the example to a document so people could run it and see the output. (most table generators make very poor tex, and it's usually better to code the tex markup directly) although the code you show doesn't look as bad as some. Depending what result you want, perhaps you just want to use `[t]` instead of `[c]` on all those nested tabular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this conversion that you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|p{20mm}|*{3}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}p{21mm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
\textbf{Task} & \textbf{Description} & \thead[l]{Associated\\ Strategy} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Exemplar} & \thead[l]{Non-exemplar,\\ other info. } & \thead[l]{Topical\\ turn coding} \\
\hline
%
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{lc}\multirow{15.2}{*}{\makecell[l]{Common\\ ground - \\ update}}
 & \multirow{16}{=}{Describing information known by other communication partners. This may include: \newline ![enter image description here][1]][1]\newline introducing new people to an ongoing joint project or explaining information known by other communication partners.}
 & Explanation
 & Definition of term, \newline%
 description of how something works (e.g. treatment), how to complete a task, often related to medical or ED processes
 & Interpreter defining colloquial term "mad de orine" which does not have a direct translation
 & Falls into updating common ground (not maintaining) when information is known by other communication partners
 & \multirow{4.5}{=}{Current turn} \\
 \cline{3-7}& &
& \multirow[t]{2}{=}{Specifically occurs when a new communication partner enters an exchange and are informed about what they have missed in the exchange}
& Interpreter arrives, clarifies point in patient's care with registrar
& & \\
\cline{5-5}
&
 & \multirow{-2}{=}{Bringing up to speed} &
 & Nurse presenting %\\
 patient to tele-triage %\\
  physician
 & \multirow{-2}{=}{None} & \multirow{-2}{=}{Current turn}
\\[8ex] \cline{3-7}
& & & \multirow[t]{2}{=}{Catch all for asking for or providing information known by other communication partners (possibly already discussed)}
& "Let them know you can't swallow pills." – Patient wife to patient
& \multirow[t]{2}{=}{Specific to care of given patient as opposed to explanations of ED or medical processes which would be classified as explanation}
& \\
\cline{5-5}
& & \multirow{-2}{=}{Providing/ gaining information}
&
& Patient asking nurse for updates on tests doctor was ordering
&
 & \multirow{-2}{=}{Current turn}
 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3116396, since above answer gives "exactly what you looking for", why you not accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer)?